# Proper way to change the way a Repeater renders content

Tags: c#, repeater

I'd like to render content that is subject to presentation change.

For example, if an item was upvoted by the current user, the up arrow should be highlighted, likely through a class change or something of that nature.

A Repeater is designed for much more homogeneous rendering, it seems. In the past, my solution has been to use objects to build HTML strings, and then bind a simple string array to the repeater.

Is there a better path where some kind of if/then logic can be applied to a Repeater? Is there an alternative to the Repeater that is more fitting for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a class attribute that is empty if the current user hasn't updated. Something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="upvote();" 
    class="<%# ((bool)Eval("CurrentUserHasUpvoted")) ? "on" : "off" %>">Upvote</a>
```